# how to properly align list items vertically?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a list of items by displaying a name, a list of properties and an image. Although this seems like quite a common and easy problem, I am struggling to get it right.

After having changed the markup a dozen of times, I chose to represent the list by a `ul` in which each `li` consists of a `h3`(name), a `ul`(properties) and a `img`(image).

In order to make it fill the page a bit more, I used CSS's `flexbox` in order to put the image and the properties next to each other in a responsive way.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100px;
}

#example > ul > li {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

h3 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

div > ul {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<section id="example">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>Bulbasaur</h3>
      <div>
        <span>Properties</span>
        <ul>
          <li>green</li>
          <li>seed</li>
          <li>grass</li>
          <li>poison</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/2/21/001Bulbasaur.png" />
    </li>

    <li>
      <h3>Charmander</h3>
      <div>
        <span>Properties</span>
        <ul>
          <li>orange or some kind of red, I am not completely sure</li>
          <li>lizard</li>
          <li>fire</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/7/73/004Charmander.png" />
    </li>

    <li>
      <h3>Squirtle</h3>
      <div>
        <span>Properties</span>
        <ul>
          <li>blue</li>
          <li>tiny turtle</li>
          <li>water</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/3/39/007Squirtle.png" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

This looks pretty nice when the properties for all elements are equally long, but it kind of looks messy when this is not the case (the property-lists are not properly aligned as indicated by the red lines in the above snippet). I know I could get all the content in a table, causing every table element to be aligned nicely under each other, but then I don't know how I can have my names in a different line than the properties and the image...

My question could thus be formulated as:
How can I align the properties nicely under each other in such a way that they are displayed next to the image (to fill the space on the screen)? Additionally I would like that the image is displayed under the properties when the screen becomes too small (i.e. responsive design) and a separate line for the name.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

---

### Update:

As it turned out that my question is not that clear, I tried to make it more clear by adding the vertical red lines in the snippet. I manage to get the desired result when using a table, but then I have to omit the names (as shown in the attached image) and the responsiveness...

[image: desired result without names]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a simple item element, something like this:

#### HTML

```
<li class="item">
  <h2>Charmander</h2>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Properties</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>orange or some kind of red, I am not completely sure</li>
      <li>lizard</li>
      <li>fire</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/7/73/004Charmander.png" />
  </div>
</li>
```

I simply divided the element in three main sections: *title*, *properties* and the *image*. 
As you can see the properties are still inside a `<ul>` because they are used like a enumeration.

#### CSS

```
#example > ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  background: #CCC;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Padding will be inside the element (will not affect the width/height) */
  margin: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Used to keep the floated element inside the flow */
}

.item h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.item .content {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item .image {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
}

.item .content ul {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

With the first selector (`#example > ul`) I reset the default `padding` it has.

The text of the properties will just start on a new-line if it is too long (you can test this by resizing the window).

You can just edit the `padding-left` of the `.content` element, to move the properties a little bit more to the right or to the left.

## [Example JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpjoe9vf/4/)

---

This is just to give you an example of how you want to approach this.

Hope it was helpful!

Comment: I'm afraid my question was unclear, please take a look at the updated question. Also I am more a fan of having the image wrap under the text instead of being squeezed...

Comment: @MrTsjolder Alright, made an update. Hope this is what you mean (tried to add the responsive design you described)

Comment: It looks wonderful, but one thing is not completely clear to me: Why shouldn't I use a list like this? To me it seems semantically more meaningful to be a list (enumeration of pokemons), although I don't completely display it like a list...

Comment: @MrTsjolder You are totally right... There was no clear reason for me discarding the list idea. It IS a enumeration of pokemons. Thank you for questioning me, haven't seen alot of people do that :P Apologies for my sloppy answers. Updated the answer with the list elements.

Answer (score 1):

I have just been so stupid. As an alternative to the [helpful answer of nkmol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35708969/4375377), it could also be as simple as changing the `justify-content` property to `space-between` and correct it by setting width and auto-margins.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100px;
}

#example > ul > li {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

h3 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

li > div > ul {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<section id="example">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>Bulbasaur</h3>
      <div>
        <span>Properties</span>
        <ul>
          <li>green</li>
          <li>seed</li>
          <li>grass</li>
          <li>poison</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/2/21/001Bulbasaur.png" />
    </li>

    <li>
      <h3>Charmander</h3>
      <div>
        <span>Properties</span>
        <ul>
          <li>orange or some kind of red, I am not completely sure</li>
          <li>lizard</li>
          <li>fire</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/7/73/004Charmander.png" />
    </li>

    <li>
      <h3>Squirtle</h3>
      <div>
        <span>Properties</span>
        <ul>
          <li>blue</li>
          <li>tiny turtle</li>
          <li>water</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/3/39/007Squirtle.png" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

PS: I'm sorry for my awful question...

Answer (score 0):

You need to break out your items from the primary UL

You can think of it as though you were building a table, but instead, use divs and then use a UL just to list the properties. This way, you can style each of the individual elements as needed.

look here: https://jsfiddle.net/oq04f6pm/2/

```
<section id="example">
    <div class="section-title">Bulbasaur</div>
    <div class="section-list">
        <span>Properties</span>
            <ul>
              <li>green</li>
              <li>seed</li>
              <li>grass</li>
              <li>poison</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="section-image">
        <img src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/2/21/001Bulbasaur.png" />
    </div>
</section>


img {
  max-width: 100px;
}


.section-title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.section-list, .section-image {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.section-image {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .section-list, .section-image {
  width: 100%;
  }
  .section-image {
  text-align: left;
}
}
```